# Clojure macro that builds a higher order function from a function

Tags: macros, clojure

I'm trying to write a macro that builds middleware akin to that used in compojure.

I want to be able to call:

```
(def-middleware plus-two [x]
  (+ 2 x))
```

And have the result look like:

```
(defn plus-two [f]
 (fn [x]
   (f (+ 2 x)))
```

I've got this far from reading on-line guides but it's not working out for me:

```
(defmacro def-middleware [fn-name args & body]
  '(defn ~fn-name [f]
     (fn ~args
       (f ~@body))))
```

Any help or a pointer to a better macro writing guide would be great, thanks.

Comment: How is it not working out for you?

Comment: CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: First argument to def must be a Symbol, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:33)

Comment: use the back-tick, not the single quote

Comment: Thanks Alex, can't believe i did that ... but now i get: CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't use qualified name as parameter: user/f, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:55)

Comment: I think you want to replace the occurrences of f with f# (the latter generates a symbol within a template expression)

Comment: As a suggestion, I think it would be more helpful to post things like your error back as an edit to your original question. It's not a biggie, but just a suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's see what `macroexpand-1` gives us:

```
user=> (clojure.pprint/pprint (macroexpand-1 '(def-middleware plus-two [x] (+ 2 x))))
(defn
~fn-name
[f]
$
(fn ~args$ (f (clojure.core/unquote-splicing body))))
```

Not precisely what we're after! First things first: if you want to unquote things in a macro, you need to use "`" (the quasiquote/syntax-quote operator), not "'". Also, I'm not sure what you're after with those dollar signs, but it *might* be that you're going for the clojure's handy shortcut for using `gensym` for hygiene. But you need it immediately after each identifier you use it with (so `[f#]`, not `[f]$`), and you need it on each occurrence of the identifier. And you *don't* need it with `args`. Putting all this together:

```
user=> (defmacro def-middleware [fn-name args & body] `(defn ~fn-name [f#] (fn ~args (f# ~@body))))
#'user/def-middleware
user=> (clojure.pprint/pprint (macroexpand-1 '(def-middleware plus-two [x] (+ 2 x))))
(clojure.core/defn
 plus-two
 [f__594__auto__]
 (clojure.core/fn [x] (f__594__auto__ (+ 2 x))))
nil
user=>
```

Comment: Sorry the $ where form copying and pasting from vim. And you're right it was the # i was missing :) thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is just a macro exercise, but the specific example of defining a middleware function is not good - you lose a lot of the flexibility that the middleware concept gives you. For example, why should this evaluate `(f (+ 2 x))` instead of `(+ 2 (f x))`? Both are sensible ways to wrap this function, and your syntax gives no way to describe the latter. Really just defining a function-returning-function is flexible, simple, and easy; this macro brings little to the table.

Comment: Thanks amalloy; I'm using it as a stepping stone to both learn macro's and also build more specific middleware-like building functions as opposed to this big dumb one that just wraps something... As you're right, as it currently stands, this one can't short-circuit, etc and its not descriptive about how it wraps things,etc.